# Assign Credentials to specific Database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, credentials

I want to assign user name and password on specific database in SQL Server 2005. Kindly tell me its solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create new login like "test" by right click on Security >> Logins in SSMS. In "User Mapping" section select database for which you need to assign credentials and select required rights like below :

[image]